# Piping vs Buffering to Upload Files in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

As far as I know there are two canonical ways to respond with a file in Node.js:

Firstly, and the most common way I'm sure, is to load the file into memory and forwarding the data argument of a callback. In example:

```
if(stat && stat.isFile()){
    fs.readFile(d,function(a,data){
        response.writeHead(200,{
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        response.write(data);
        successCallback();
    })
}
```

Additionally, there is the method which to pipe the data as it's being read. In example:

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.mp3'),
    stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath),
    readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);

response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
});
readStream.pipe(response);
```

Now, clearly the latter approach has its clear advantage in memory conservation, especially considering large files or streams. However **is it the best catch-all method?** In situations where I'm processing (comparatively) small but numerous files such as HTML, scripts, and bitmaps am I better off with the former, text-book method?

So, for all intents and purposes, what's going on under the hood, and what circumstantial overhead may dissuade me from using readStreams all the time, if any?

Comment: Did you do a performance test on each of the methods? The results would be interesting to see, as well as maybe give you your answer.

Comment: @grebneke Not exactly something I can just throw into jsperf and I'm not that familiar with nodeJS benchmarking suites. Would really like to know what's happening under the hood though.

Comment: You might write a script looping through a list of files, downloading them 100 or 1000 times with each of the methods, measuring the time it takes.

Comment: And here I have a fun ultimatum. A: confirm I'll do just that and no-one will bother doing it for me. or B: Wait for someone else to do it for me and look like I've been bumming on reddit the entire time. Former it is then; more after the break! (Still would love a mechanics breakdown if someone's got it)

Comment: Tests are more useful for *specific cases*. It's difficult to test a *general case* since it could be just anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the source for [fs.readFile](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L172) and [fs.createReadStream](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1408) respectively, I'd say `createReadStream()` is the better catch-all method. Regardless of size, the data still has to be read from disk. But if the data is large, there is a performance-/resource hit allocating buffer memory to store it before sending.

`ReadStream` in `node` is optimized to be fast - it's used for http responses and requests for which `node` is so famous.

In a specific case where you keep sending a limited number of smaller files repeatedly, there are advantages in caching the data. You would then read all the files with `readFile` at *application start*, store them in a hash and send them directly from memory on each request. If you can spare the memory, it will always be fastest to avoid the filesystem all together during the request cycle.

But as a general rule, pipe the data to the client asap without intermediate memory storage.

Comment: Now is that later bit on the presumption that I'm caching those files?

Comment: @TERMtm - sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: In "sending a limited number of smaller files repeatedly" is there some backend caching mechanism associated with readFile? And it's only under the circumstance I'm sending the **same** file more than once correct?

Comment: There is no caching at all in readFile, except for the underlying OS filesystem layer (VFS) cache, but that's another story. No - I was thinking that if you have say 100 small files that you keep serving constantly, it might be faster to read them all into an array or hash at application start, and then just send them directly from memory whenever needed. If you can afford the memory, this will definitely be the fastest of all.